# How to state Curry's Paradox in propositional logic?

Tags: logic

Can Curry's Paradox be stated in propositional logic as:

> $[A\iff [A\implies B]] \implies B$

This is a tautology.

Note that:

> $[A\iff [A\implies B]] \equiv A\land B$

Comment: If it is a tautology, it's kind of unlikely to be a paradox .....

Comment: @PeterSmith Some call $\neg A \implies [A \implies B]]$ a "paradox." It, too, is a tautology.

Comment: @DanChristensen Who are those some?

Comment: @NoahSchweber  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradoxes_of_material_implication

Comment: @DanChristensen Ah. Regardless, it's a paradox on a very different level than Curry's paradox; we can neutralize Curry by rejecting material implication, but Curry's paradox is much more than just standard $\implies$-manipulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not [Curry's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%27s_paradox). *(I'm sure you're familiar with what I write below; I'm including it for completeness and the benefit of other readers.)*

Curry's paradox is used to "prove" an arbitrary claim, assuming the "admissibility" of a certain kind of self-referential statement. Namely, given an arbitrary sentence $\varphi$, Curry examines the sentence $$(*)_\varphi\quad\mbox{If this statement is true, then $\varphi$}.$$ This has the form "$A\implies\varphi$," and in order for it to be false $A$ must be true. That much doesn't rely on self-reference.

However, where self-reference comes in is in the observation that this situation can't occur: $$\mbox{$(*)_\varphi$ is false $\implies$ the hypothesis of $(*)_\varphi$ is true $\iff$ $(*)_\varphi$ is true;}$$ so we get "$\neg(*)_\varphi\implies(*)_\varphi$," that is, $(*)_\varphi$ is **true**.

Now we simply apply modus ponens to get $\varphi$.

When cast as a theorem, Curry's paradox amounts to a limitation, in any nontrivial formal system, on either the *kinds* of self-reference expressible in that system or the *extent* to which the standard rules of logic hold for such self-referential sentences within that system.

As you observed, the sentence you write down is not paradoxical; it is missing the **self-referentiality** which is  crucial to Curry's paradox. What it is is the observation that makes the Curry paradox "tick:" we apply it to the assumption that "This sentence implies $\varphi$" is expressible in our system. But it's wrong to say that this *is* Curry's paradox; rather, Curry's paradox *relies on* the validity of the principle. This is a worthwhile observation since in weak formal systems (e.g. I believe [relevant logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relevance_logic)) Curry's paradox can break down.

Comment: So, you agree that classical logic avoids CP?

Comment: @DanChristensen Since classical logic is consistent, it avoids *every* paradox.

Answer (score 0):

You can try QSAT, in classical logic you get:

$$\vdash_C \forall P.(Q \leftrightarrow (Q \rightarrow P)) \rightarrow \forall P.P$$

One of the interesting challenges could be to show  the same in non-classical logic. It then depends how you read the propositional quantifier. If you only assume this distributivity (K-rule) of propositional quantifier in your non-classical logic:

$$\begin{array}{c}
 \hline
\vdash_M \forall P.(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (\forall P.A \rightarrow \forall P.B)\end{array}$$

and this introduction rule (N-rule):

$$\begin{array}{c}
 \vdash_M A \\
 \hline
 \vdash_M \forall P.A\end{array}$$

The non-classical logic could be minimal logic, because in minimal logic this here is derivable:

$$ \vdash_M(Q \leftrightarrow (Q \rightarrow P)) \rightarrow P$$

The rest would then follow from N-rule and K-rule in the corresponding propositional quantified minimal logic.